# How to join in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

How can I get the count is 0 if it is null. when I run with the following statement:

```
SELECT S.shortText, COUNT(O.selectionID) AS C FROM Opinions O
LEFT JOIN Selections S ON S.id=O.selectionID
WHERE S.qID=3 AND MONTH(O.entryDate)=5 
GROUP BY S.shortText
```

---

```
 shortText         C    
 ----------------  ---- 
 Leisure           0       <------ this line missing 
 Business          3
 University visit  1
```

My Selections Table

```
 id     shortText        
 -----  ---------------- 
 1      Leisure          
 2      Business         
 3      University visit
```

My Opinions Table

```
 id     entryDate              selectionID    
 -----  ---------------------  -------------- 
 186    5/21/2012 11:34:37 AM  2              
 205    5/22/2012 9:13:25 AM   2              
 216    5/22/2012 9:43:14 AM   2              
 237    5/24/2012 8:24:00 PM   3
```

Comment: What is S.qID? there is no column named qID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the Leisure rows as 0 even there is no matching record in opinions table. Use subquery as below:

```
select t1.shorttext,if(t2.c is null,0,t2.c)as c from selections t1 left join (

SELECT s.id,S.shortText, COUNT(O.selectionID) AS C FROM selections S
LEFT JOIN opinions O ON S.id=O.selectionID
WHERE  MONTH(O.entryDate)=5 
GROUP BY S.shortText
  ) t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ca3e/11

Answer (score 1):

If you want that to show, interchange the `Selections` and `Opinions` table.

```
SELECT S.shortText, COUNT(O.selectionID) AS C 
FROM   Selections S
       LEFT JOIN Opinions O 
         ON S.id=O.selectionID
-- WHERE  S.ID=3 AND                     -- add extra conditions here
--       MONTH(O.entryDate)=5 
GROUP BY S.shortText
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39159/7)

or use `RIGHT JOIN`

```
SELECT S.shortText, COUNT(O.selectionID) AS C 
FROM   Opinions O 
       RIGHT JOIN Selections S
         ON S.id=O.selectionID
-- WHERE  S.ID=3 AND 
--       MONTH(O.entryDate)=5 
GROUP BY S.shortText
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39159/14)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried swapping the tables?  SELECT from SELECTTIONS and join to OPINIONS, not the way you have it.